# getting list of top space consuming files and remove it

Tags: xargs, rm, du

I am using `du -hsx * | sort -rh | head -10` to get top 10 space consuming files in directory. So I would like to know how to pass output of above command and delete those files. I know about `xargs` but I don't know how to incorporate it in my command, so any help would be appreciated ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
du -sxh * | sort -rh | head -10 | xargs rm -fr $1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please explain what $1 will do ?

Comment: `$1` is the input to the xargs received from the output generated from head

Answer (score 1):

You can do,

```
du -sxh * | sort -rh | head -10 > out
cat out | xargs rm -fr $1
```

Comment: where $1 is output of first one as input of second one.